# How to add extra data to the ckeditor using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am working on MVC3 CKeditor and I need to insert some extra data into CKeditor when I click the submit button. How can I do this? My code so far is as follows: this is my html page

```
        <div id="div-child-Cat-Desc-Long" class="CKEditor-child-DIV">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { Class = "input-xlarge", @id = "txtAreasocial",@rows="3" })
                </div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    //Passing the Text Area reference to get the CK Editor
    var editor = CKEDITOR.editor.replace('txtAreasocial');
});

 $('#btnadd').click(function () {
    alert('hi');

    var data = "Hello. This is a new node.";
    alert(data);
    CKEDITOR.editor.setData(data);

    editor.setData(data)
});
```

Comment: extra data means.. what?  what u exactly want ?

Comment: extradata means i wil get selected check box value like product
 and like category  type i need to add it  to ckeditor

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure how many instances of CKeditor do you have. You need to get the editor's instance and use `setData` method to add data to a particular instance. For Example:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(data)
```

or

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(data)
```

check the `setData` method in the [documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html).

Comment: i had tried but its not working tahnk ypu for my reply more help please

Comment: do you get the alert --> clicking fired ?

Comment: did you use `editor.setData(data)` ? what error does it give you  ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21641/discussion-between-shakil-and-amyth)

Answer (score 1):

> Use "insertHtml" or "insertText" function for appending data into the CKEDITOR. Like this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['input-text-area-ID'].insertHtml(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

- make a new child element

  ```
  var txtNode = document.createTextNode("Hello. This is a new node.");
  ```
- then append it into your editor..

  ```
  txtNode.appendTo($('#editor'));
  ```

Comment: i had tried but its not working tahnk ypu for my reply more help please