# How to add content in ckeditor using jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add dynamic content in ckeditor I have also used CKEDITOR.instances or some another thinks which I get from Stack Overflow but I can't get output.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea class="ckeditor form-control" name="Content" id="emailcontent" >
     <?php echo $valuedata[0]['email']; ?>
</textarea>`

i am using ck-editor java script and text area.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the entire editor content, use [`setData()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable-method-setData), for example:

```
CKEDITOR.instances[Name].setData(Data)
```

If you want append data into the editor window, you can use [`insertHtml()`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#insertHtml) and [`insertText()`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#insertText) methods

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in jquery by assigning value to editor like

```
CKEDITOR.instances['emailcontent'].setData(data)
```

Here you can populate data. Find below detail here

[How to add extra data to the ckeditor using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021424/how-to-add-extra-data-to-the-ckeditor-using-jquery)